# AngularJS - Use Instant Search with JSON file

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I have just started using AngularJS and have been experimenting with the "Instant Search" module.  Instead of hard coding .json data into the controller, I would like to use an AJAX call to fetch a separate .json file.

Angular Instant Search Controller Javascript Code with Hard Coded Items:

```
function InstantSearchController($scope){

$scope.items = [
    {
        url: 'http://tutorialzine.com/2013/07/50-must-have-plugins-for-extending-twitter-bootstrap/',
        title: '50 Must-have plugins for extending Twitter Bootstrap',
        image: 'http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/featured_4-100x100.jpg'          
    },
    {
        url: 'http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/simple-registration-system-php-mysql/',
        title: 'Making a Super Simple Registration System with PHP and MySQL',
        image: 'http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/simple_registration_system-100x100.jpg'
    },
    {
        url: 'http://tutorialzine.come/2013/08/slideout-footer-css/',
        title: 'Create a slide-out footer with this neat z-index trick',
        image: 'http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/slide-out-footer-100x100.jpg'
    },
    {
        url: 'http://tutorialzine.com/2013/06/digital-clock/',
        title: 'How to Make a Digital Clock with jQuery and CSS3',
        image: 'http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/digital_clock-100x100.jpg'
    }


];


}
```

I would like to replace '$scope.items' with an AJAX call to a .json file.  I know this involves using $http' as a parameter but am not sure on how to properly make this call.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#controller

Comment: Thanks for the link above!  Got it working now!

Comment: @numbers1311407 please propose this as an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has excellent documentation in the form of both a full API reference and a walkthrough tutorial full of working examples.

See the documentation for `$http` here:

- [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

And how it could be used in a sample application here:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#controller

Essentially, your code using `$http` would look something like:

```
$scope.items = $http.get('path/to/your.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.items = data;
});
```